# highstock selected rangeSelector is computed from the current end date in the slider and not from the start date

Tags: highcharts

using `highcharts@9.1.1`

I am rendering a chart with initial `rangeSelector = 1y` but it's not rendering properly, the chart selects the last year of data instead of the first year. my data is ordered asc by timestamp btw.
same happens when I explicitly select a range, it computes the range from the current end date in the slider as opposed to the start date.

how can I make it behave differently?

https://jsfiddle.net/6vLgdrx7/4/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setExtremes` method in chart's `load` event and set the initial selected area.

```
chart: {
  ...,
  events: {
    load: function() {
      const xAxis = this.xAxis[0];
      xAxis.setExtremes(
        xAxis.dataMin,
        xAxis.dataMin + (xAxis.max - xAxis.min),
        true,
        false
      );
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hm4xLzft/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#setExtremes

Comment: thanks. that would help with the initial render, but what about when a range is selected? I want my period computed from the current start date forward, and not from the current end date back as is the case now.

Comment: Hi @kfc, You can define your own callback function for click in range selector buttons. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8gL25q10/